# WPF type handling difference between VB and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am working through a book on WPF and learning the input events. I'm on touch events. I also tend to program in VB, though I generally can read C#.

I believe the sample code below (both C# and VB) is sufficient for my question.

```
protected override void OnTouchMove(TouchEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTouchMove(e);

    if (e.TouchDevice.Captured == canvas)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

Protected Overrides Sub OnTouchMove(e As TouchEventArgs)
  MyBase.OnTouchMove(e)
  If e.TouchDevice.Captured.ToString = canvas.ToString Then
    ' Do stuff
  End If

End Sub
```

I had to add the `.ToString` in the If statement because VB wouldn't evaluate the expression like C#.  Here's what Visual Studio fed back for the 2 variables in each language.

```
C#
  e.TouchDevice.Captured - IInputElement TouchDevice.Captured
  canvas                 - Canvas MainWindow.Canvas
VB
  e.TouchDevice.Captured - Read Only Property TouchDevice.Captured as IInputElement
  canvas                 - WithEvents TouchWindow.Canvas As Canvas
```

Is this just life in VB, or is there some setting I could change to have VB evaluate the equality without ToString?

The .XAML file was the same for both projects

Comment: Use `Is` in VB for reference comparison.

Comment: That was quick and it worked perfectly.  Thx.  Did you want to write that as an answer?

Comment: Ugh... one more reason to hate VB. Note that `is` in C# will return if a cast to the type is possible.

Comment: Also, this is a lousy way to do WPF.  Once you get the basics down take on some MVVM.

Comment: @Will.  I'm not what I would consider a 'guru' in software (i.e. not someone with 98,378 reputation, so yes, there are things I haven't been exposed to yet; it all comes with time - right?  And maybe some encouragement?  And this walk through 'basic' WPF began because I started with the Prism MVVM framework & quickly realized I needed a little more WPF learning so I decided to go through a book page by page doing every example.  So now I'm learning the little things that come second nature to those more erudite.

Comment: That's great, sounds like you'll be fine.  Still, dump VB.  The power of my fake internet points compels you!